# Amplify Studio deleting something in my database from the website doesn't sync with my code

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

For some reason my aws amplify database is out of sync with my code.

So in my code I have this line
`const games = await DataStore.query(GameState)` which just grabs all the queries in my database. So I would have one object in my database and I would delete that object from my database via the website, yet the query would still return that object.

I have no idea why this is happening. If I delete my models and aws-exports files then repull everything it seems to sync up, but the moment I delete something via the aws amplify website my code becomes out of sync again.

Any ideas? Thank you.

/// Update ///

So I found out if I swap my import of DataStore from

`import { DataStore } from 'aws-amplify';`

to

`import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';`

and vice versa the database will sync up but then if I delete anything on the amplify website it will be out of sync again. Seems to be an issue with using the amplify website?